# python: for i in range trouble

Tags: python, for-loop, range

This is my code:

```
 for i in range(self.inputCount, len(self.neurons)):
        currNode=self.neurons[i]
        for k in range(len(currNode.inNeuron)):
            print 'len(currNode.inNeuron) =', len(currNode.inNeuron)
            print 'range(len(currNode.inNeuron)) =', range(len(currNode.inNeuron))
            print 'k =', k
            if currNode.inNeuron[k] == editNode:
                currNode.inNeuron.pop(k)
```

For some reason whenever I run this and len(currNode.inNeuron) is 1 and range is [0], k is 1. I want k to only be zero in this case. Here is a sample of the printed output

```
range(len(currNode.inNeuron)) = [0]
k = 0
len(currNode.inNeuron) = 1
range(len(currNode.inNeuron)) = [0]
k = 0
len(currNode.inNeuron) = 2
range(len(currNode.inNeuron)) = [0, 1]
k = 0
len(currNode.inNeuron) = 1
range(len(currNode.inNeuron)) = [0]
k = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neuralnet.py", line 99, in <module>
    if __name__=="__main__":main()
  File "neuralnet.py", line 95, in main
    net1.randomizeNet(5)
  File "neuralnet.py", line 84, in randomizeNet
    self.eraseNode()
  File "neuralnet.py", line 52, in eraseNode
    if currNode.inNeuron[k] == editNode:
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: *sigh* and what's the error?

Comment: don't change element used in `for` - you get element from `currNode.inNeuron.pop(k)` but `for k in range(len(currNode.inNeuron))` doesn't know it.

Comment: Your loop uses `for k in range(len(currNode.inNeuron)):`. The parameter to the range function `len(currNode.inNeuron)` is evaluated at the start of the loop. So when there are 2 items in `currNode.inNeuron`, the loop will run twice, even if you change the items in `currNode.inNeuron` during the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this a try,

```
 for i in range(self.inputCount, len(self.neurons)):
    currNode=self.neurons[i]
    for k in range(len(currNode.inNeuron)):
        print 'len(currNode.inNeuron) =', len(currNode.inNeuron)
        print 'range(len(currNode.inNeuron)) =', range(len(currNode.inNeuron))
        if( len(currNode.inNeuron == 1 && range(len(currNode.inNeuron == 0)) )
            print 'k = 0'
        else
            print 'k =', k
        if currNode.inNeuron[k] == editNode:
            currNode.inNeuron.pop(k)
```